# Check for new items in an existing list LINQ/LAMBDA/C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to extract new Details added to the list. So I want to basically compare the two lists to eliminate new items based on two criterias.

This example works correctly when there is one criteria:

```
var newDetails = item.BranchDetails.Where(ibd => !CartItemsDetails.Select(cid => cid.BRANCH_ID).ToList().Contains(ibd.BranchId)).ToList();
```

I want to take it further and check against, when BranchIds are equal and LotNumber. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Could you explain how is your second condition?

Comment: `when BranchIds are equal and LotNumber` what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method instead, it will let you to define a boolean expression where you can compare several properties:

```
var newDetails = item.BranchDetails
                    .Where(ibd => !CartItemsDetails
                                   .Any(cid => cid.BRANCH_ID==ibd.BranchId 
                                            && cid.LotNumber==ibd.LotNumber))
                    .ToList();
```